# How to get Audio back if using UseEDID "false" in xorg.conf (Nvidia304)

Tags: audio, x11, xorg, hdmi, edid

My Ubuntu machine has previously worked fine, then I upgraded.

The issue is with no xorg.conf it boots, works all ok.... But

The display (A panasonic PDP) has a broken modeline (you get 1cm of RHS screen on LHS), so needs a custom one. The only way to activate the modeline is with xorg.conf and unless UseEDID "false" it always goes to the display given EDID.

BUT with UseEDID as false, since the update, the machine has no audio. UseEDID = true and we have audio. I have booted back and forth... it is just the one line that goes from bad display/audio to noaudio/good display

Tried Nvidia 304 340 352 official.

So anyone can help with the best way forward.

```
    Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown" 
    ModelName      "BNO Beovision 4-5"
    HorizSync       31.2 - 48.4
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 60.3
    Modeline "1366x768"   86.709   1366 1399 1580 1793   768 771 777 806  -hsync -vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option "UseEdidFreqs" "False"
    Option "UseEDID" "False"
    Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "True"
    Option "ModeValidation" "HDMI-0: AllowNonEdidModes, NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck, NoMaxPClkCheck, NoVertRefreshCheck, NoHorizSyncCheck, NoEdidMaxPC

    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Modes   "1366x768"  
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: You may jave better luck on superuser or askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the modes/modeline name to a mode name that was not already used on edid

Eg 1366x768 to 1366x768_custom